# about putting words with particular length into a corresponding Set (Java)

Tags: java, set

I have a dictionary.txt which has many vocab. I want to sort those vocab according to their word length. For that, I intend to create a Set for each particular word length, and put words with that length into that set.

I have thought of creating many sets by myself, ie. creating sets:

```
Set<String> wordLength1 = new TreeSet<String>();
Set<String> wordLength2 = new TreeSet<String>();
Set<String> wordLength3 = ...;
```

but it is too clumsy to do it - I may have to create at least twenty to thirty sets.

What's more, I dont know what is the maximum number of length of a word (I dont wanna scan the whole dictionary.txt first in order to get the maximum word length... a bit clumsy). Is there a way that is: to create a new set only if I find that the word length correspond to a set that I have not created before. eg. if the input word has a length of 7, and I find that I have not created a set called wordLength7, then I create it; else I just simply put it into that set.

And is there a method to put a word into a set besides the following clumsy method?

```
if (word.length() == 1) {
wordLength1.add(word);
} else if (word.length() == 2) {
wordLength2.add(word);
} else if (word.length() == 3) {
wordLength3.add(word);
} else if ...
```

Comment: you can make a map of Sets and create them somewhere internally, but store them in this map with length of word as a key

Comment: oh, good idea. i think it helps. thx. 
but do u have some idea about the problem that: creation of set only if i encounter a word with new word length?

Comment: Oh i think i know how to solve it. I can simply examine if the map contains the key, which is the word length. if no, then I create a new set into the map.
Thx a lot for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Map that maps the length to the set of words.

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> lengthToWords = new HashMap<Integer, Set<String>>();
```

and fill it like this

```
Set<String> words = lengthToWords.get(word.length());
if(words == null) {
  words = new TreeSet<String>();
  lengthToWords.put(word.length(), words);
} 
words.add(word);
```